# Retry for useEffect in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional component that fetchs some data from an API and show it somewhere in the page, the thing is when an error occurred I want to display a retry button to call the API again. so I did this:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import api from "../../../api";
import {useSnackbar} from "notistack";

const ShowPassword = ({uuid}) => {
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);
    const [retry, setRetry] = useState(false);
    const {enqueueSnackbar} = useSnackbar();
    useEffect(() => {
        api.showPassword(uuid)
            .then(res => {
                setPassword(res.data.password);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setRetry(true);
                enqueueSnackbar('An error occured...', {variant: 'error'});
            })
    }, [password]);

    return (
        <div>
            {
                retry
                    ? <button onClick={() => {
                        setRetry(false);
                        setPassword(null);
                    }} type='button'>Retry</button>
                    : <span>{password ?? 'Loading...'}</span>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShowPassword;
```

but by clicking on the **Retry** button, It displays `Loading...` but the API won't be called again.

Comment: useEffect dependency array [password] is unchanged in error scenario. Need to add some "change var" here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on event of error "password" value not changed. Add some value to password (or some change to indicate in useEffect dependency array).

```
onClick={() => {
    setRetry(false);
    setPassword("some value");
}}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to set null again to the `password` but react finds it as a different value and re-render the component? Or maybe there is a way to tell react that this state has changed something like a force state change

Comment: @Omid, I think you can add setPassword(null) just before making api call in use effect.  Alternative to the proposed fix, you can maintain new state variable 'retryCount' and increase the count onClicking the retry button (and add it to dependency array). This way you can control of number of trails allowed as well.